# How can I non-randomly set the height and width of the page where I'm working on?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to set the height and width of my page but I realized that I don't understand what I'm doing. For example, I take the body and I set an height of:

```
body {
heigh: 500px /*or 800px or 600px or whatever!*/
}
```

I do this because I'd like my elements inside the body to not be attached to the body top and bottom edge. I'd like them to have space between all the edges.

I know that the `html`  and the `body` don't have thickness by default. But how do I set my `body` or `html` height? I mean, I did set it until now (like I've written in the example) but I feel that those values that I put in are totally random! Why should I put a value instead of the other one? Why to put 600px insted of 800px?

So, according to what do I specify the height of my page? How to do it?

Thank you all!

Comment: Height of body `min-height: 100%;`

Comment: @zer00ne Hi! Ok, I knew that trick. You can do it with `100vh` also. But don't you have to set the html `height: 100%` first? Because without that it doesn't work to me and also I have to set the body as `height` and not `min-height`. Instead, if I only use the body height set like `height: 100vh` it works. But besides all this, could you explain me what is the point of all this? Because it looks to me that using these values we are trying to set the body height like that one of the screen and then it will automatically adjust according to what happens inside body, am I right?

Comment: Yep, I usually start layout from the inside and work my way outwards. If you have a `min-height`, `height` isn't necessary unless it's bigger than the `min-height`.

Comment: @zer00ne But what is the main difference between `height` and `min-height`? It looks to me that with`min-height` you set, of course, the minimum height BUT if something inside gets higher the parent element that you set `min-height` to will adjust its height accordingly. `height` instead looks like you set an height and, no matter what happens inside the parent element that you set the `height` to, the height won't adjust and the content of the parent element, if gets higher, overflows. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Pretty much, you got the general idea. That's why I start from the inside, but that's just a habit of mine developed over the years and not from analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have a specific size of edge for the page, and would rather manipulate on the body. You can try setting "margin" or "padding".

```css
body {
    padding: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Hi! No my aim would be to have my `body` taking the hole screen size height as a starting point and then adjusting automatically its height while I put more and more stuff inside it.

Comment: @91Flavio91 I don't think I unerstand your problem. What you're describing just seems to tbe the actual default behavior of body. Perhaps add some illustration to better help interpret what you're trying to achieve?